# add-apt-repository not found in docker image

Tags: docker, apt

I'm trying to setup a docker container for some ML work, for which I need CUDA and Conda. I setup the docker image with this command:

`docker run -it continuumio/anaconda3:2020.11`

In order to setup CUDA, I am following [these instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=deb_local).

The steps in the link are:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-debian11-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb 

dpkg -i cuda-repo-debian11-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb

cp /var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-8-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

add-apt-repository contrib

apt-get update

apt-get -y install cuda
```

However, the steps fail when trying to run `add-apt-repository contrib`. Based on other threads, I've tried:

`apt-get install software-properties-common`

however, that fails as well:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_241-7~deb10u4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.94.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-sysv_241-7~deb10u4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.94.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-minimal_3.7.3-2+deb10u2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.94.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.7/python3.7-minimal_3.7.3-2+deb10u2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.94.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.3-2+deb10u2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.94.132 80]
...
```

How do I get this installed?

Comment: What is your actual Dockerfile?  You generally need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single `RUN` command; otherwise Docker layer caching can result in individual package "not found" errors like what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you build a derived image which wraps up both Anaconda and CUDA. There seem to be two obvious approaches:

- Anaconda base image and install CUDA; or
- CUDA base image and install Anacoda.

Based on a bit of experimentation the second approach appears to be better.

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-base-ubuntu22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget -q https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && \
    rm Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh

ENV PATH /root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

# Python packages for testing.
#
RUN conda install -y -q numba cudatoolkit
```

Assuming you are on a machine with an NVIDIA GPU and you have the drivers installed you can test the connection to the GPU. You need to run the image with the `--gpus all` option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this gets me half way there. Is there a container with the toolkit? I need `nvcc`.